# 7za execute via terminal emulator android

Tags: android

Im going to use 7za library
now i try to use 7za to extract files and add files from 7z
My problem is that every time i execute nothing happen

Here is my 7z.sh code 
and also i set permission and its on /data/local/d

```
#!/system/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=
umask 000
cd "$1"
shift
/data/local/d/7za "$@"
```

and in terminal i execute using

```
su
cd /data/local/d/
sh 7z.sh x -tzip d.zip
```

And i getting error
Incorrect command line and x : no such file directory

Help me  thanks for solution

Comment: Are you running this on Android?  If so, you're making lots of invalid assumptions about the filesystem setup.  If not, why is this tagged android?

Comment: Its on android i try to execute